# I am taking user input and splitting it - how to best check types for each and also remove spaces?

Tags: javascript

i'm not sure if there's a better way to do this.

basically, just taking user inputs for example - `hair salon, 1, 4`

when I split by `,` i get `['hair salon',' 1',' 4']`.  I am doing an error check to make sure its always only 3 values passed max, but how can I remove the spaces (`' 4'`) and also check that `'hair salon'` is a string, and the other two are numbers?

Thanks

Comment: `split()` will always return string array so first elemnt will be always string

Comment: thanks but is there a way to check if the other two elements can be changed to number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have user input as

```
hair salon, 1, 4
```

Now you split(','), you will get an array as

var arr = ['hair salon', '1','4']

You will get every input as string

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
 arr[i] = arr[i].trim() // will remove space from back & front
}
```

In case you needed to get the data type of inputs, you can check that using

```
typeOf (arr[i])) - in the for loop itself
```

Hope, it suffice your need

Answer (score 1):

Since `split()` returns string array so all elements will be string . you can convert your second and third parameter with `parseInt()`. If  value cannot be converted to a number it will return NaN:

Try this code:

```
var str="hair salon, 1, 4"
var val=str.split(', ');

var a=parseInt(val[1]);
var b=parseInt(val[2]);
var c=a+b;
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following function `validateInput` to validate user input:

```
function validateInput(str){

    var items = str.split(",").map((v) => v.trim());
    if (items.length > 3 
            || typeof items[0] !== 'string' || /^[\d-]+$/.test(items[0])
            || isNaN(Number(items[1])) || isNaN(Number(items[2])))
    {
        if (validateInput.items) validateInput.items = null; // clear previous input items
        throw new Error("Invalid data!");
    }
    validateInput.items = items;

    return true;
}
validateInput.items = null;  // static property containing valid user input

console.log(validateInput("hair salon, 1, 4"));  // true
console.log(validateInput.items);                // ["hair salon", "1", "4"]

console.log(validateInput("-8, 7, e"));  // will throw "Error: Invalid data!"
```